# Can I dynamically add HTML within a div tag from C# on load event?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net-3.5, master-pages

Mind you, I am using master pages, but can I locate a div within the page and throw some html in there? Thanks.

Comment: Are you talking about within a page or control and of which on the server or client side?  There are a few different sides to this, I think but generally the answer is yes though YMMV.

Answer (score 84, accepted):

You can add a div with runat="server" to the page:

```
<div runat="server" id="myDiv">
</div>
```

and then set its InnerHtml property from the code-behind:

```
myDiv.InnerHtml = "your html here";
```

If you want to modify the DIV's contents on the client side, then you can use javascript code similar to this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    Sys.Application.add_load(MyLoad);
    function MyLoad(sender) {
        $get('<%= div.ClientID %>').innerHTML += " - text added on client";
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks a ton. Deadline of app moved up, really needed this code. thanks again

Comment: I used your approach and used it quite well with a `stringbuilder` and returning a serialized string to js side. Do you mind if I add it into your answer. Because without the serialization certain double quoted strings will not be properly transferred from C# to js.

Comment: Does this still works ? I tired and it doesn't work for me.

Answer (score 15):

Use `asp:Panel` for that. It translates into a div.

Answer (score 5):

Remember using

```
myDiv.InnerHtml = "something";
```

will replace all HTML elements in myDIV. you need to append text to avoid that.In that this may help

```
myDiv.InnerHtml = "something" + myDiv.InnerText;
```

any html control in myDiv but not ASP html controls(as they are not rendered yet).

Answer (score 3):

You could reference controls inside the master page this way:

```
void Page_Load()
{
    ContentPlaceHolder cph;
    Literal lit;

    cph = (ContentPlaceHolder)Master.FindControl("ContentPlaceHolder1");

    if (cph != null) {
        lit = (Literal) cph.FindControl("Literal1");
        if (lit != null) {
            lit.Text = "Some <b>HTML</b>";
        }
    }

}
```

In this example you have to put a Literal control in your ContentPlaceholder.

Answer (score 1):

You want to put code in the master page code behind that inserts HTML into the contents of a page that is using that master page?

I would not search for the control via FindControl as this is a fragile solution that could easily be broken if the name of the control changed.

Your best bet is to declare an event in the master page that any child page could handle. The event could pass the HTML as an EventArg.

Comment: Can give an example?