# ASP.NET how to AppendChild that will appear on top

Tags: asp.net, xml, appendchild

I have been using appendChild to attach items to a div.

The default behaviour is to attach items to the bottom of the container div,  but I want items to be appended to the top.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've already figured it out. instead of putting AppendChild, I changed it to PrependChild. and it works good.

Answer (score 1):

try using [insert before](http://www.w3schools.com/dom/met_element_insertbefore.asp)

```
parentDiv.insertBefore(newDiv, parentDiv.firstChild);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot guys. but I've already figured it out. instead of putting AppendChild, I changed it to PrependChild. and it works good. :)

Answer (score 0):

**javascript:** You have to insert in not append it :).

**c# (asp.net):** div.innerHTML = custom_html + div.innerHTML

**link:** [Can I dynamically add HTML within a div tag from C# on load event?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/467016/can-i-dynamically-add-html-within-a-div-tag-from-c-sharp-on-load-event)

Comment: Thanks a lot guys. but I've already figured it out. instead of putting AppendChild, I changed it to PrependChild. and it works good.